# Why do aliases with words not expand in big sur?

Tags: big-sur, alias

I have some aliases in my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` (I tried with and without .bash_profile), they were both sourced.

```
alias ll=‘ls -l’ 
alias al=‘ls -ahl’

alias iridium=“~/git/iridium”
alias vscode=“Visual Studio Code”
```

On Ubuntu, centos and fedora these would work fine.

Even on windows git bash I had long aliases to open games with the huge steam path.

But on big sur:

only the ls aliases work.

is there a reason for this?

I’m also sourcing these files from `/etc/bashrc`

Look at it in action:

```
 λ  cat ~/.bash_profile 
alias ll='ls -l'
alias al='ls -ahl'

alias vscode='Visual Studio Code'

alias batchelor="~/git/batcheloranator"
alias iridium="~/git/iridium"
alias chem="~/git/chemistry_stuff"
 chemistry_stuff:  (master)  
 λ  . ~/.bash_profile 
 chemistry_stuff:  (master)  
 λ  cd iridium
bash: cd: iridium: No such file or directory
 chemistry_stuff:  (master)  
 λ  cd chem
bash: cd: chem: No such file or directory
 chemistry_stuff:  (master)  
 λ  open -a vscode
Unable to find application named 'vscode'
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got what I wanted by doing this:

```
 λ  cat .bash_profile 
alias ll='ls -l'
alias al='ls -ahl'

vscode='Visual Studio Code'

batchelor=~/git/batcheloranator
iridium=~/git/iridium
chem=~/git/chemistry_stuff
 
 ~:    
 λ  open -a "$vscode"; echo $?
0

 ~:    
 λ  cd $iridium
 iridium:  (master)  
 λ
```

Comment: It appears you were confusing aliases (which hold executable commands, and must occur where a command name would normally be) and variables (which hold data, and must be expanded with `$`). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172982/what-is-the-difference-between-alias-and-export-and-a-functionbash/23173661#23173661) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ alias --man
NAME
  alias - define or display aliases

SYNOPSIS
  alias [ options ] [name[=value]...]

DESCRIPTION
  alias creates or redefines alias definitions or writes the existing alias definitions to standard output. An alias
  definitions provides a string value that will replace a command name when the command is read. Alias names can
  contain any printable character which is not special to the shell. If an alias value ends in a space or tab, then the
  word following the command name the alias replaces is also checked to see whether it is an alias.
```

If you want your vscode alias to work, you need to do something like:

```
alias vscode='"visual studio code"'
```

So that the shell doesn't perform word-splitting on the string.

Example:

```
$ alias vscode='visual studio code'
$ vscode
ksh: visual: not found               <= shell word-splitting
$ alias vscode='"visual studio code"'
$ vscode
ksh: visual studio code: not found   <= shell not word-splitting
$
```

But what you really should do is follow VS Code's installation instructions for macOS, add `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin` to your path, and run `code` to start it.

```
$ path
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
/Users/mwilson/bin
/Users/mwilson/.local/bin
/Users/mwilson/Library/Python/3.9/bin
$ whence code
'/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code'
$
```